# Passive Link in Angular 2 - <a href=""> equivalent

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing, angular-router

In Angular 1.x I can do the following to create a link which does basically nothing:

```
<a href="">My Link</a>
```

But the same tag navigates to the app base in Angular 2. What is the equivalent of that in Angular 2?

**Edit:** It looks like a bug in the Angular 2 Router and now there is [an open issue on github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7294) about that.

I am looking for an out of the box solution or a confirmation that there won't be any.

Comment: You still can. It's just html. Any particular use for it?

Comment: Yes, it is still valid html, but the effect is not the same with Angular 1.x.

Comment: Did you try just `<a>`, without "html"?

Comment: Yeah, but than the browser doesn't treat it in the same way. I know I can override i.e. the cursor effect with css, and assign pointer to all `a` tags. But that looks hacky.

Comment: My opinion is that ng1 way was the wrong way (: Default behavior should be as it is in standard html...

Comment: Totally agree with @Sasxa, to be honest that sounds like a useless "feature". Why would a framework hijack my html by default and not let it work as it should?

Comment: I am not sure about how passive links to be handled but it is not a useless feature, at least for me. It is quite handy, for example, when you want to use a link to access controller.

Comment: @EricMartinez I think the issue here is less about whether or not Angular should hijack the default behavior, but rather that Angular's router requires the use of the `<base>` tag, so when you click on an `<a href="#">` link rather than navigating to `#` you end up at `/#` or whatever your base href is. Interested to see how this pans out in the GitHub issue.

Comment: I have the same problem i solved it with  a([routerLink]=""). it is in pug which is equal to <a  [routerLink]=""></a>

Answer (score 275, accepted):

If you have **Angular 5** or above, just change

```
<a href="" (click)="passTheSalt()">Click me</a>
```

into

```
<a [routerLink]="" (click)="passTheSalt()">Click me</a>
```

A link will be displayed with a hand icon when hovering over it and clicking it won't trigger any route.

**Note:** If you want to keep the query parameters, you should set `queryParamsHandling` option to `preserve`:

```
<a [routerLink]=""
   queryParamsHandling="preserve"
   (click)="passTheSalt()">Click me</a>
```

Comment: This generates a href="#/" at DOM (angular 4)

Comment: This worked `[routerLink]=""` it renders as `<a href="null" (click)="myFunction()">My Link</a>` Angular 5 in Chrome 64.

Comment: I can confirm the same `[routerLink]=""` / `href="null"` is working in IE 11

Comment: <a [routerLink]="" (click)="passTheSalt()">Click me</a> works in angular7. I see <a (click)="passTheSalt()">Click me</a> without routerLInk works in angular7 as well. what is better way to make a passive anchor link using [routerLink] or no routerLink?

Comment: @IanPostonFramer When I remove `[routerLink]=""`, the text _Click me_ is not displayed as a link and does not show hand cursor icon.

Comment: Why not just remove the href and replace it with nothing? We have CSS, so that negates the concern of the styles.

Comment: The accepted answer will reset the scroll position to the top, which may not be desirable in all situations.

Comment: NOTICE: this will reset your URL params. buyer beware.

Comment: What about when you Right-click → Open in New Tab?  The fact that it actually tries to navigate to /null at that point makes me weary of this approach.

Comment: Use <a href="" (click)="false">

Comment: In Angular 11, it generates: `<a href="(currentURL)">...</a>`. On click, it won't trigger any route.

Comment: You might need to use `routerLink=""` rather than `[routerLink]=""`

Comment: `[routerLink]=""` works in angular 13 but it will not have hand cursor. How to fix this?

Comment: What is this "passTheSalt" method?

Comment: You can call that if `isFoodTasteless` equals `true` @dancab

Answer (score 109):

That will be same, it doesn't have anything related to `angular2`. It is simple html tag.

Basically `a`(anchor) tag will be rendered by HTML parser.

**Edit**

You can disable that `href` by having `javascript:void(0)` on it so nothing will happen on it. (But its hack). I know Angular 1 provided this functionality out of the box which isn't seems correct to me now.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" >Test</a>
```

[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/SW87p9xrAPP4QDyXwzVJ?p=preview)

---

Other way around could be using, `routerLink` directive with passing `""` value which will eventually generate blank `href=""`

```
<a routerLink="" (click)="passTheSalt()">Click me</a>
```

Comment: @s.alem what ever you are saying, that having `#` inside anchor `href` can affect `Angular1` route..may send you to default page(if its there)

Comment: I know the effect of `#` in angular 1.x. I want a link that does nothing in angular2, just like `href=""` in angular 1.x.

Comment: @s.alem so `<a href="">My Link</a>` will do that..but what happening currently with it?

Comment: It navigates to the app base like I said in my edit.

Comment: Yeah, that would be a solution, but looks hacky. I still feel like there should be an out of box solution like in angular 1.x.

Comment: This notation can generate errors in the console, fyi. such as: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load javascript:void(), Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

Comment: @John this seems to be causing because of some chrome extension.. I also had some issue with my application when my app was handling CORS, it was getting failed

Comment: @PankajParkar Interesting, but it's an error reported by angular. We stepped away from using `<a>` elements without a valid href, too many problems with the Angular2 routers, instead, we use a `<span>` element with a link class and things work much better for us.

Comment: Could you try to reproduce that error private window (as extension doesn't work there) It should work properly in that case..

Comment: You can disable the `href` in a less hacky way using `preventDefault` like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44465069/702783

Comment: A content security policy may block this answer, try `[routerLink]=""`. It will cause a `href="null"` to render.

Comment: [routerLink]="" will remove query params from your route, this is likely not what you want. You could use preserve query params, but this seems like going too far

Comment: The second options *does not work* for me in AngularDart, using `[routerLink]=""` with `(click)="navigateFunc(id)"` will send me back to the root `/`.  If pushing back I get the navigation url I wanted and then if I push back again I get to my original page.  The browser goes to both urls basically.

Comment: However, option 1: `href="javascript:void(0);"` DOES work for me.

Answer (score 22):

There are ways of doing it with angular2, but I strongly disagree this is a bug. I'm not familiarized with angular1, but this seems like a really wrong behavior even though as you claim is useful in some cases, but clearly this should not be the default behavior of any framework.

Disagreements aside you can write a simple directive that grabs all your links and check for `href`'s content and if the length of it it's 0 you execute `preventDefault()`, here's a little example.

```js
@Directive({
  selector : '[href]',
  host : {
    '(click)' : 'preventDefault($event)'
  }
})
class MyInhertLink {
  @Input() href;
  preventDefault(event) {
    if(this.href.length == 0) event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

You can make it to work across your application by adding this directive in PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES

```js
bootstrap(App, [provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: MyInhertLink, multi: true})]);
```

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vCcSuv6e1pEPesjEwlf0?p=info) with an example working.

Comment: Upvote for a global, angular solution, but I'm not accepting it as the correct answer because as I said, I'm only looking for an out box solution, until they confirm there won't be any or until I really really need it. But still thank you very much.

Comment: The problem with `pointer-events` is the lack of support with IE ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events)) (I can bypass it even with IE11 weirdly enough), and it doesn't prevent to *click* the link from the console. I've upvoted @Pankaj answer because it's the easiest one from my point of view, my answer is just a way of doing it with angular2, I could make it easier but css selectors are limited.

Comment: This seems to break bootstrap tab links (such as <a href="#tab-id"> )

Comment: Which module is bootstrap function in?

Answer (score 17):

An achor should navigate to something, so I guess the behaviour is correct when it routes. If you need it to toggle something on the page it's more like a button? I use bootstrap so I can use this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" (click)="doSomething()">My Link</button>
```

Comment: I like this solution. If you want to have cursor to show a hand, add style="cursor: pointer".

Comment: In many situations a good solution, however be aware that the button has bigger dimensions than just the text based anchor.

Comment: @yankee you can change that in css, but I don't recommend... fact is, a button is a button, and a link is a link... too sad the web is not that white or black.

Answer (score 16):

I am using this workaround with css:

```
/*** Angular 2 link without href ***/
a:not([href]){
    cursor: pointer; 
    -webkit-user-select: none; 
    -moz-user-select: none; 
    user-select: none
}
```

html

```
<a [routerLink]="/">My link</a>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is a better solution as it's mainly a visual effect that's missing. You can put this CSS in the Angular project's top-level `styles.css` file and it will work great!

Answer (score 13):

[simeyla solution](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7294#issuecomment-264068778):

```
<a href="#" (click)="foo(); false">
<a href="" (click)="false">
```

Comment: This appears to be the simplest and most elegant solution.

Comment: Simple answer 

Comment: just return false in the function, then you don't have to remember it in every tag you use the function.

Answer (score 8):

Here are some ways to do it:

- `<a href="" (click)="false">Click Me</a>`
- `<a style="cursor: pointer;">Click Me</a>`
- `<a href="javascript:void(0)">Click Me</a>`

Answer (score 6):

I have 4 solutions for dummy anchor tag.

```
    1. <a style="cursor: pointer;"></a>
    2. <a href="javascript:void(0)" ></a>
    3. <a href="current_screen_path"></a>
```

4.*If you are using bootstrap:*

```
<button class="btn btn-link p-0" type="button" style="cursor: pointer"(click)="doSomething()">MY Link</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have prevent the default browser behaviour. But you don’t need to create a directive to accomplish that.

It’s easy as the following example:

*my.component.html*

```
<a href="" (click)="goToPage(pageIndex, $event)">Link</a>
```

*my.component.ts*

```
goToPage(pageIndex, event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(pageIndex);
}
```

Comment: This will go over updates and doesn't deal with routerlink or null values.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why people suggest using `routerLink=""`, for me in Angular 11 it triggers navigation.
This is what works for me:

```
<div class="alert">No data yet, ready to <a href="#" (click)="create();$event.preventDefault()">create</a>?</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple way

```
  <div (click)="$event.preventDefault()">
            <a href="#"></a>
   </div>
```

capture the bubbling event and shoot it down

Comment: Why not use the anchor itself for preventing the default behavior? Like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44465069/702783 

Seems less »hacky« to me.

Answer (score 4):

Updated for Angular 5

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:directive-selector
  selector : '[href]'
})
export class HrefDirective {
  @Input() public href: string | undefined;

  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) public onClick(event: Event): void {
    if (!this.href || this.href === '#' || (this.href && this.href.length === 0)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case deleting href attribute solve problem as long there is a click function assign to a.

Answer (score 2):

A really simple solution is not to use an A tag - use a span instead:

```
<span class='link' (click)="doSomething()">Click here</span>

span.link {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn’t do that in the sense of sematic markup. Use a `button` Element in case you want to `doSomething` on the page.

Comment: `<button>` elements trigger click by default when the `space` key is pressed. Using `span` (or `<a>`) removes this feature - so keyboard actions won't work as expected

Comment: yeah, i appreciate the solution but this breaks accessibility for many of us

Comment: This is never the right solution.  Spans are meant for formatting text, anchors for linking, and navigation, Accessibility tools handle these differently.

Answer (score 2):

From **Angular 13** and onwards, the behavior of `routerLink` has changed ([source commit](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/ccb09b4558a3864fb5b2fe2214d08f1c1fe2758f)). To create a link that does nothing (while still having the "hand" icon) use the following:

```
<a routerLink="." queryParamsHandling="preserve"></a>
```

This will populate the link's `href` attribute with a link to the current page, so nothing happens when clicking on it.
Keep in mind, that the `queryParamsHandling="preserve"` is necessary if your current route has any query params set to not remove them when clicking the link.

Answer (score 1):

you need to prevent event's default behaviour as follows.

In html

```
<a href="" (click)="view($event)">view</a>
```

In ts file

```
view(event:Event){
 event.preventDefault();
 //remaining code goes here..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why no one is suggesting routerLink and routerLinkActive (Angular 7)

```
<a [routerLink]="[ '/resources' ]" routerLinkActive="currentUrl!='/resources'">
```

I removed the href and now using this. When using href, it was going to the base url or reloading the same route again.

Answer (score -3):

Updated for Angular2 RC4:

```
import {HostListener, Directive, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[href]'
})
export class PreventDefaultLinkDirective {

    @Input() href;
    @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick(event) {this.preventDefault(event);}

    private preventDefault(event) {
        if (this.href.length === 0 || this.href === '#') {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Using

```
bootstrap(App, [provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: PreventDefaultLinkDirective, multi: true})]);
```