# Angular 2, handle anchor links with href='#'

Tags: angular

When clicking any anchor link which has a `href='#'`, the Angular router path

```
{ path: '', component: NologinComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
```

is matched, How should I handle these anchor links so that anchor with `href='#'` stays on same page, i.e do nothing.

Example anchor tag

`<a class="title-logo" href="#"><img src="/Content/Images/Image1.png"></a>`

One More point to consider, i have used the  `<base href="/" />` in the layout page so that on refresh angular stays on current page and look for the resources from "/" not from inside the current component.

Comment: What exactly is the point of `href="#"`? Or do you mean `href="#something"`?

Comment: @zeroflagL just suppose i have some links for which the href has not been defined, for example the privacy page, so i have kept it #, so on click of this link nothing should happen, but instead it redirects to login page

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a few options:

**Option 1:**

Override `href` attribute with a directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector : '[href]'
})
export class MyLinkDirective {
  @Input() href: string;

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  noop(event: MouseEvent) {
    if(this.href.length === 0 || this.href === '#') {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35641429/1784230)

Personally, I like this solution because it is global and angular. Here's a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-noop-link?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-link.directive.ts).

---

**Option 2**

You can use css and ditch the `href` attribute all together:

```
a {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Then your inactive links would be:

```
<a class="title-logo"><img src="/Content/Images/Image1.png"></a>
```

---

**Option 3**

CSS `pointer-events`:

```
a.noop {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

Usage

```
<a class="title-logo noop" href="#"><img src="/Content/Images/Image1.png"></a>
```

`pointer-events` may cause trouble on some (especially older) browsers, if you care about them. You can see the compatibility list [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events).

Comment: I have considered the option 1 from the original source but it didnt work, you can try making a plunker

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
href='javascript:void(0);'
```

Comment: @promod i have multiple anchor links, i am not going to replace all of them with this, also i want to handle this in a generic centralized way

Answer (score 1):

Since adding this functionality is tricky, I suggest you to not reinvent the wheel, take a look at [ng2-page-scroll](https://github.com/Nolanus/ng2-page-scroll).

If you'd like to investigate more, you should read the [Router & Navigation Guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#query-parameters).

Comment: i am not making the page scrolls, the problem is simply with any click for which a link is not defined.

Comment: in that case you can't use anchor links. If you need something to trigger on click, you must use the [click event](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html#!#sts=src%2Fapp%2Fclick-me.component.ts). When you build something with Angular, you need to have in mind that you're not creating a simple html static page.

Answer (score -1):

The sample way could be adding this piece of code event.preventDefault(); inside your event function ..

such as

function fn(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ...
}