# How to use anchor link in angular without changing the url in angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, scroll, angular-routerlink

I trying to navigate from a.class1 to div.class2. But the URL is changing when the link is called. So when trying to back page, it goes back to the current page on another section.

```
<a RouterLink="." [fragment]="'idDiv'" class="class1"></a>
...
<div class="class2" id="idDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple add 'skipLocationChange' to your anchor tag

```
<a routerLink="." [fragment]="'idDiv'" class="class1" skipLocationChange></a>
```

You can also refer to this one: [Angular 2, handle anchor links with href='#'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43275297/angular-2-handle-anchor-links-with-href)